# Is it fair to include a product url that is related to Project Management in a Question?

Tags: discussion

I have a Project based Calendar template on a digital market and I would like to improve my product based on Project Manager's (or related Persons') ideas.
But I would like to know that, is it allowed to put my product url to the question (question will be; what you will need more to select this product to buy) for illustrate the work?
Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, thanks for asking on Meta first :)

**TL;DR:** highly likely to be considered offtopic.

Although self promotion could be [OK from a StackOverflow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57497/limits-for-self-promotion-in-answers?rq=1) perspective (also [HERE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/211770/is-it-ok-to-self-promote-a-package-library-tool-you-have-developed-as-a-q-a?rq=1) and [HERE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86717/defining-the-limits-of-self-promotion)), I don't see any way you could raise a question with PM perspective that you'd answer and won't fall into the [off-topic software recommendations](https://pm.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) category.

If you can overcome the software recommendation barrier, go ahead ns answer. :)

Comment: Thank you for your answer and references.